# Could the EDTA coating of tubes kill blood fed mosquitoes?

Tags: red-blood-cell, mosquitoes, vector, edta

Problem is as follows: culex pipiens fed with freeze-thawed cattle blood sampled in 9ml EDTA tubes enjoy their meal and thrive. Same population fed with freeze-thawed human blood sampled in 4 ml EDTA tubes die. 4ml tubes are overall quite less filled, hence hypothesis is remaining EDTA is more concentrated possibly leading to the death of the mosquitoes. Is this something plausible?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried using other sample tubes? For example heparin or citrate coated?

Comment: Not yet, i'd like to solve that mystery of cattle versus human blood

Comment: Put them in the same sized tubes?